# How to pull only certain items from all the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am pulling from the Alpha Vantage API. If I only want to pull the closing price from this dictionary for all the days. What do I do?  I don't want to print but I want to save a new dictionary that only has the closing price:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-09-28",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-09-28": {
            "1. open": "114.1900",
            "2. high": "114.5700",
            "3. low": "113.6800",
            "4. close": "114.3700",
            "5. volume": "21647811"
        },
        "2018-09-27": {
            "1. open": "114.7800",
            "2. high": "114.9100",
            "3. low": "114.2000",
            "4. close": "114.4100",
            "5. volume": "19091299"
        },
        "2018-09-26": {
            "1. open": "114.4700",
            "2. high": "115.0550",
            "3. low": "113.7400",
            "4. close": "113.9800",
            "5. volume": "19352025"
        },
        "2018-09-25": {
            "1. open": "114.8000",
            "2. high": "115.1000",
            "3. low": "113.7500",
            "4. close": "114.4500",
            "5. volume": "22668014"
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and `dict.items`. Since you are dealing with numeric data, you will likely also want to convert to `float`. Given an input dictionary `d`:

```
closes_dict = {k: float(v['4. close']) for k, v in d['Time Series (Daily)'].items()}

{'2018-09-28': 114.37,
 '2018-09-27': 114.41,
 '2018-09-26': 113.98,
 '2018-09-25': 114.45}
```

Comment: This answer's great too!  How do you add the opening price to each key?

Comment: `add the opening price to each key` - not sure precisely what you mean. You could change `'4 close'` to `'1. open'`, or use a list, e.g. `[float(v['1. open']), float(v['4. close'])]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the dict argument is what you get from the API. This will return `{'2018-09-28': ('114.1900', '114.3700'), '2018-09-27': ('114.7800', '114.4100'), '2018-09-26': ('114.4700', '113.9800'), '2018-09-25': ('114.8000', '114.4500')}` If you don't understand something or want help please feel free to ask in the comments.

```
def getCloseOpen(alphaAPI):
    days = alphaAPI["Time Series (Daily)"]
    targData = {}
    for day,data in days.items():
        targData[day] = (data["1. open"],data["4. close"])
    return targData
```

Comment: This is great!  Thank you

Comment: Please don't shadow built-ins, i.e. don't use `dict` as a variable or argument name, use `dict_` or `input_dict` or `d`, etc.

Comment: Is there a way for me to get the opening and closing price at the same time?

Comment: yes, I have updated my answer, for future reference, to get another data part, just add `data["key"] ` to the end of `targData[day]`